# Add TableRow xml layout to TableLayout on button click

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a layout xml file I am trying to append to a TableLayout when the user clicks a button. Here is my onClick listener method:

```
addHazardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.safety_question_table);
        View row = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety_question_table_row, table);
        table.addView(row);
    }
});
```

I have also tried replacing the line `View row = getLayoutInflater....` with the following:

```
View row = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety_question_table_row, null);,
&
TableRow row = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety_question_table_row, table);,
&
TableRow row = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety_question_table_row, null);
```

I have also tried passing the LayoutInflater from the onCreateView method to the method my onClickListener is set in and using it, but I don't think that is the problem, as the stack trace is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null
>   object reference

How do I properly add my xml layout file to the table onClick?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/task_step_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border_outline"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hazards_not_covered_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border_outline"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/reduce_risk_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/border_outline"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.safety_question_table);
```

instead of

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.safety_question_table);
```

Because `TableLayout` is probably in Activity layout instead of in Button View.

OR

if `TableLayout` is in parent View of `Button` then we can also access it as:

```
    View parent = (View)view.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        TableLayout table = 
           (TableLayout)parent.findViewById(R.id.safety_question_table);
        // add your code here
    }
```

Comment: The TableLayout was in the parent view, and that worked for me. Thank you very much